# What should I consider when deciding how many processes to run on an application host?

Tags: centos, cpu, top, load

I work in operations, and as such am the primary decision maker for some deployments of our services. I work with a distributed application that involves several types of "services", some more demanding than others. I say "services" because I don't want to be confusing -- these are multiple instantiations from the same C++ executable, just with different parameters to tell the exe which service type to start up as.

So traditionally, the way we've deployed our services in the past is a `1:1` ratio of `service-counts:cores` -- `cores` here are specifically that. Not `hyper-threaded cores`.

**Example!**

- Host with `4` physical CPUs, each with `4` cores.
- In `/proc/cpuinfo` this host shows up as having `32 processors` -- this is not what I mean when I say `cores` from here on. What I mean is the `4cpus x 4cores == 16 cores` total.

Our system is not multi-threaded in the sense that services work in parallel on the same scenario at the same time. It is distributed, but not *threaded*. Our services don't share much memory with each other across threads (mostly DB info I think). That's probably important information to know.

My question is, considering that our software isn't technically *threaded* in that it doesn't attempt to leverage threaded computation (it's primarily *distributed* to handle load), should I even care about `service:core` ratios at all? I feel like this is wasting a bunch of unused cycles that could be taken up by other services.

**Example!**

- Host with 16 cores, running 16 processes:  `Load average: 2.94 2.96 3.01`
- Service load is around `40%`, each (16 of the same type of service on this box)

Even though the load average is comparatively low, we still follow a policy of `1:1`. I'm not super educated on the intricacies of memory bus contention (i.e., threads on the same core will contend for access to the same memory bus), but it seems that we should be able to host several more processes on this host, considering the `Load average` isn't anywhere near `16`, the number of cores on the system.

---

### The Question!

What should I be considering here when suggesting a new policy of ignoring the `service:core` ratios mostly, and instead primarily focusing on the service load, and box load as KPI? Are there more granular details I should consider for this sort of application?

Answer (score 2):

Other factors beyond the load average include memory usage, context switching, and disk or network I/O (or ephemeral port pressure, depending on how gratuitous the services are at using ports), especially as more services are bundled together on a single host. Also, a 100% loaded system might tip over into disaster around when the daily or weekly or monthly cron jobs fire up (fun fact: the OOM killer used to kill `sshd`, usually at 04:00 AM due to the cron dailies) so leaving some spare capacity might be handy.

What sort of service monitoring do you have? If you've latency and throughput metrics for the service(s), then you could test out different configurations and compare those results to your current baseline case. (If things get worse, then you can go look for what the bottleneck is...)

Also, if there's more piled up on single systems, how bad is the recovery if that box catches on fire, compared to your current setup?

Comment: Hey, appreciate the answer! Specifically, I'm only concerned with CPU metrics currently, as this seems to be the defacto decision point that we rely on.